# Turning on LED immediately after Deep Sleep w/ ESP32-C3

Tags: microcontroller, esp32, gpio, arduino-ide

I have a slight problem in my code such that my LED does not illuminate immediately after deep sleep. The wakeup reason is GPIO go low so that when a button is depressed, the esp will wake up. That same button is also supposed to turn the LED on which is why I have implemented a counter so that it can turn on on the first depress. However, what happens is that the depress wakes up the esp and does not increment the counter so it needs an additional press/depress for the led to turn on. Is there a way I can make the led turn on at the same time as the esp waking up without using an additional button? Perhaps a way to increment the counter at the same time that the esp wakes up? Thanks for the help!

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Preferences.h>

const int buttonPin = 3;  // # for button pin for States/Interrupt
const int buttonPin2 = 2; // # for button pin for BLE
const int ledPin =  5;   // # for the Green LED pin
const int ledPin2 = 6;   // # for the Red LED pin
const int ledPin3 = 7;    // # for the Blue LED pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;     
int lastButtonState = 0;
int buttonState2 = 0;
int lastButtonState2 = 0;  
int ledState = 0;
RTC_DATA_ATTR int counter = 0; 

#define SERVICE_UUID        "f0e279fc-a979-4ffd-924c-59ced5392948"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "7f98738e-382d-43d9-b256-3cf8bd3120b7"

BLEServer *pServer = NULL;
BLEService *pService = NULL;
BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = NULL;

Preferences preferences;

bool deviceConnected = false;
class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = true;
      Serial.println("True");
      delay(3000);
      Serial.println("Going to Sleep");
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);  // Turn off LED
      esp_deep_sleep_start();  // Enter deep sleep mode
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = false;
      Serial.println("Disconnected!");
      Serial.println("Advertising...");
      pServer->startAdvertising(); 
    }
};

class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks
{
  void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic)
  {
    std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();

    if (value.length() > 0)
    {
      Serial.println("*********");
      Serial.print("New value: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
      {
        Serial.print(value[i]);
      }

      Serial.println();
      Serial.println("*********");
    }
  }
};

void setupBLEServer(void) {

  Serial.println("Starting BLE Server!");
  BLEDevice::init("Pirouette-IoT-Device");
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

  pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY);

  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());

  pCharacteristic->setValue("device_state_0_stored");
  pService->start();
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);  // functions that help with iPhone connections issue
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x12);
  pAdvertising->start();
}

void pairing(){

  digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);
  setupBLEServer();
}

void print_wakeup_reason() {
  esp_sleep_wakeup_cause_t wakeup_reason;

  wakeup_reason = esp_sleep_get_wakeup_cause();

  switch (wakeup_reason) {
    case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_EXT0:
      Serial.println("Wakeup caused by external signal using RTC_IO");
      break;
    case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_EXT1:
      Serial.println("Wakeup caused by external signal using RTC_CNTL");
      break;
    case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_TIMER:
      Serial.println("Wakeup caused by timer");
      break;
    case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_TOUCHPAD:
      Serial.println("Wakeup caused by touchpad");
      break;
    case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_ULP:
      Serial.println("Wakeup caused by ULP program");
      break;
    case ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_GPIO: //New wakeup reason <-- 
      Serial.println("Wakeup caused by a GPIO");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.printf("Wakeup was not caused by deep sleep: %d\n", wakeup_reason);
      break;
  }
}

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
  
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);

  //Enable GPIO Wakeup from buttonPin
  //esp_deep_sleep_enable_gpio_wakeup(1 << buttonPin, ESP_GPIO_WAKEUP_GPIO_HIGH);
  esp_deep_sleep_enable_gpio_wakeup(1 << buttonPin, ESP_GPIO_WAKEUP_GPIO_LOW);
  gpio_set_direction((gpio_num_t)buttonPin, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);  // <<<=== Add this line

  //Set up preferences for led state
  preferences.begin("led-state", false);
  counter = preferences.getInt("counter", 0);
  
  preferences.putInt("counter", counter);
  preferences.end();

}

void loop(){
  
  // read the state of the BLE pushbutton
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
  if (lastButtonState2 == HIGH && buttonState2 == LOW) {
    Serial.println("The button is pressed");
    pairing();
  }
  lastButtonState2 = buttonState2;
  
  //Wake-up ESP from deep sleep
  print_wakeup_reason();
  
  
  // read the state of the internal pushbutton:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    // if the state has changed, increment the counter
    if (lastButtonState == HIGH && buttonState == LOW) {
      counter++;
      Serial.print("Number of button pushes:  ");
      Serial.println(counter);
      // if the current state is HIGH then the button went from off to on:
      ledState = !ledState;
    }
    if(counter == 2){
        buttonState = lastButtonState;
    }
  }
  // save the current state as the last state, for next time through the loop
  lastButtonState = buttonState;

  // sets the LED to the button's state
  if(counter == 1){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
    
    if(pCharacteristic != NULL){
      pCharacteristic->setValue("device_state_1_ready"); //add code for device 1 state ready once buttonPin1 is pushed/released
      pCharacteristic->notify();
    }
  }
  
  if(counter == 3){
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    
    if(pCharacteristic != NULL){
      pCharacteristic->setValue("device_state_3_locked"); //add code for device 1 state ready once buttonPin1 is pushed/released
      pCharacteristic->notify();
    }
  }
  else if (counter >= 4){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
  }

  delay(50);
  }
```

I have also tried to use the preferences.h library to store the counter, but I think I may have implemented that wrong as well. Any help on getting the LED to turn on at the same time as the board wakes up from deep sleep is really appreciated!

Comment: "_Perhaps a way to increment the counter at the same time that the esp wakes up?_"  Yes, why not do that?  Just increment the counter in the ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_GPIO case in print_wakeup_reason().

Comment: Your idea almost worked perfectly, but the counter incremented by more than a factor of 1 for some reason which threw the rest of the code off. However, you sparked a great idea in me which is to replace the counter++; with a digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); in the print_wakeup_reason. This ended up working exactly as intended. Thank you for your help and sparking this idea!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);` in the right case for the print wake-up reason